# Mixed model for non-normal continous data

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, glmm, gamma-distribution

I am dealing with longitudinal data (Visual analogue scale (0-10)), and my data is skewed and contained several zeros. I have missing data (MAR) and can't use ANOVA with the non-parametric test, so I was supposed to use a linear mixed model. I know whether the continuous data is normal distribution is not so important and mandatory. But the data might violate the assumption of the linear mixed model (LMM) by checking residuals and qqplots (please see below).  So I am stuck here.

Questions

1. Because this data is clinically relevant, I don't want to transform it, hope to keep the raw data. But I still tried square root for this data (because it contained 0), and it didn't improve the model.
2. I also don't want to dichotomize or ordinal these data for clinical use. Should I consider GLMM with gamma distribution? How can I deal with a value of zero in this model? (GLMMtmb)? Some papers suggest this data is beta distribution, but still we have to transform this response variable into "ratio",[0-1 scale] which I don't want to do.
3. Should I still use LMM ignoring violation? (Honestly, I wish this answer.....)

Thanks a lot.
Please don't hesitate to contact me, I am feeling anxious now!!!

[image]

[image]